# as3 - How do I make an object rotate to the crosshair instead of the mouse?

Tags: actionscript-3

I placed the arm movieclip instance inside of the player movieclip instance. The crosshair instance is placed in the player movieclip's parent.

I'm trying to get the arm to rotate by following the crosshair. I tried using mouseX and mouseY and that seemed to work except I want the arm to follow the crosshair, not the mouse. The crosshair is placed in the player movieclip's parent so I use MovieClip(parent), so I put this code in the player class' enterframe:

```
var dx = MovieClip(parent).crosshair.x - arm.x;
var dy = MovieClip(parent).crosshair.y - arm.y;
var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) / Math.PI * 180;
arm.rotation = angle;
```

However when I do this, the arm does not rotate at all. What am I supposed to be doing?

The crosshair is an instance that is outside the movieclip and has the instance name of "crosshair". It's not a variable.

The code for the crosshair is inside player's parent's enterframe:

```
crosshair.x += (mouseX - crosshair.x) / 5;
crosshair.y += (mouseY - crosshair.y) / 5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the coords inside player `MovieClip` to the coords in the same system that the crosshair `MovieClip` using `localToGlobal` and `globalToLocal`methods.

An example code:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateArm);

var crosshair:MovieClip = MovieClip(this.parent).crosshair;

//---Rotate arm function
function rotateArm(evt:Event):void{

    //---Move crosshair
    moveCrossHair();

    //---Convert the local Point to global Point
    var point:Point = new Point(this.arm.x, this.arm.y);

    var parentPoint:Point = this.parent.globalToLocal(this.localToGlobal(point));

    var dx:Number = crosshair.x - parentPoint.x;
    var dy:Number = crosshair.y - parentPoint.y;

    var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx) / Math.PI * 180;

    this.arm.rotation = angle;

}

//---Move crosshair function
function moveCrossHair():void{

    crosshair.x += (this.parent.mouseX - crosshair.x) / 5;
    crosshair.y += (this.parent.mouseY - crosshair.y) / 5;

}
```

Here you have a working example, it was built with Flash Pro but I've included a `xfl` example.

[Download Example](http://xprimiendo.com/examples/FLASH/crosshair.zip)

Comment: Oh snap, sorry. I forgot to add that to my code. But it still seems like it doesn't do the trick. It still won't rotate as it does when using mouseX and mouseY.

Comment: If you get the mouseX and mouseY of the MovieClip that contains the crosshair the result will be the same. But, if you get the mouseX and mouseY of the other MoviClip (for example the Stage) you need to convert the point with localToGlobal or globalToLocall to get the same result.

Comment: Could you please give me an example on localtoglobals? I don't think I quite understand. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should convert it to. I tried to convert the crosshair's new point to mouseX and mouseY. It did rotate as expected, but the crosshair was off-place and was not following the mouse on the screen. I added my crosshair code on the question. It's what makes it follow the mouse but with slight delay.

Comment: Put an example code with the use of mouseX and mouseY and I'll update the post.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example code, download the flash and analyze if it helps you.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I might've not explained clearly. You're example is quite similiar to mine except my rotating arm is actually inside of a movieclip called "player". Could you please try to make a movieclip called "player" and copy and paste the arm inside of it. Then change all the codes with "this.arm" to "this.player.arm" And you will see the won't rotate as expected. That's the problem I'm having. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question above to be more precise. The arm is an instance inside the player movieclip and the code is written inside the player class enterframe event.

Comment: You need to convert the coords from one MovieClip to another like I said you. I've updated the code and the zip example.

Comment: I've made some little changes in the code. Regards ;)